# How can I handle events from a control in winforms that is created in the code and not the drag/drop designer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, syncfusion

As you can see when my application starts I am creating a treeview from syncfusion named "trHome". Now I want to do something if a specific node in the tree is selected but I do not know how to handle this control which is not present in the designer.

```
Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim TreeStruct As TreeViewAdv = New TreeViewAdv()
  Dim font As Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", Single.Parse("12"))
  TreeStruct.Name = "trHome"
  TreeStruct.Font = font
  gb.Client = TreeStruct
End Sub

Private Sub trHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles trHome.Click

End Sub
```

I was hoping when I clicked on a node in the tree control my code would execute the sub trHome_Click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft tells:

```
' Associate an event handler with an event.
AddHandler Obj.Ev_Event, AddressOf EventHandler
```

for you:

```
AddHandler TreeStruct.Click AddressOf trHome_Click
```

Comment: If this form is closed before the app exits, be sure to use `RemoveHandler` to remove the event handler when you're done with the object. Not doing so prevents the garbage collector cleaning things up properly.

Answer (score -2):

The requirement is to perform some operations on a specific selected node in TreeViewAdv. This can be achieved by utilizing events.
After initializing the control, it is possible to hook into the events. The **AfterSelect** event is suitable for this scenario. In this event, necessary operations for the specific selected node can be performed.

Please find the below code snippets attached for the reference.

```
Public Sub New()
    treeViewAdv1 = New TreeViewAdv()
    treeViewAdv1.Name = "treeView1"
    treeViewAdv1.ItemHeight = 20
    Dim treeNode1 As New TreeNodeAdv("Node1")
    Dim treeNode2 As New TreeNodeAdv("Node0", New TreeNodeAdv() { treeNode1})
    Dim treeNode3 As New TreeNodeAdv("Node3")
    Dim treeNode4 As New TreeNodeAdv("Node2", New TreeNodeAdv() { treeNode3})
    Dim treeNode5 As New TreeNodeAdv("Node5")
    Dim treeNode6 As New TreeNodeAdv("Node4", New TreeNodeAdv() { treeNode5})

    treeNode1.Name = "Node1"
    treeNode1.Text = "Child1"
    treeNode2.Name = "Node0"
    treeNode2.Text = "Parent"
    treeNode3.Name = "Node3"
    treeNode3.Text = "Child1"
    treeNode4.Name = "Node2"
    treeNode4.Text = "Parent1"
    treeNode5.Name = "Node5"
    treeNode5.Text = "Child1"
    treeNode6.Name = "Node4"
    treeNode6.Text = "Parent2"

    'Add the nodes in TreeViewAdv nodes collection

    treeViewAdv1.Nodes.AddRange(New TreeNodeAdv() { treeNode2, treeNode4, treeNode6})
    treeViewAdv1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(377, 250)

    ' Add the TreeViewAdv to the Form controls
    Me.Controls.Add(treeViewAdv1)
    AddHandler treeViewAdv1.AfterSelect, AddressOf TreeViewAdv1_AfterSelect
End Sub                                                                          

Private Sub TreeViewAdv1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
If treeViewAdv1.SelectedNode.Text = "Parent1" Then
    treeViewAdv1.SelectedNode.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", Single.Parse("22"))
End If
End Sub
```